# Mott scattering vs Rutherford Scattering

Tags: particle-physics, scattering

If I am understanding the scattering rate correctly, and that is the nr. of accelerated particles that are scattered in a certain solid angle per unit time, the why the bigger the scattering angle the larger the difference in the scattering rate between the 2 types of scattering. In the graph below we can see this disparity. One reason I can think of it's because in the case of Rutherford scattering the particles are moving slower then in the case of Mott scattering, which means they are long under the effect of the repulsive electric potential/field of the nucleus, and as a result of this longer exposure, the particles ($\alpha$) deviate more from the straight trajectory that they initially do, before coming into contact with the nucleus. Is this reasoning wrong?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

From wikipedia:

> Mott scattering is similar to Rutherford scattering but *electrons are used instead of alpha particles as they do not interact via the strong force (only weak and electromagnetic).* This enables them to penetrate the atomic nucleus, giving valuable insight into the nuclear structure.

italics mine.

There is no description of your plot, or a link, on whether it is the same momentum beams or the same energy beams ( masses are different for electrons and alpha particles), The plot tells us that the scattering of alpha particles is more probable at high angles , and this should be due to the strong interaction that the electrons do not see. The electrons can propagate further into the nucleus as they do not interact strongly and have to be much closer to a scattering source to interact with it than the alpha particle.